# What are the restrictions between core data parents' concurency type and child concurency type in core data?

Tags: core-data, concurrency

Should they be the same? What kind of concurrency type the parent have?

Every time the child do executeFetchRequest, the parent is asked. What about if several children from various different thread do executeFetchRequest at the same type?

What happen if the parent is declared to have main concurency type and then a child on another thread do executeFetchRequest? Will it wait till the main thread run, and then give result, and then continue the thread? of what?

Basically I have various wait lock issue and I want to understand more about this.

Actually if there is a resource on the web on common practice on parent and child relationship for multi thread I'll be trilled. In IOS5 we need to do performBlock. Do we need to do that in all command for core data because that means a lot of change of code here.

Update:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1 is obsolete right?

Comment: The concurrency with core data section is not entirely obsolete. It details what the parent/child context system does for you. It just doesn't cover how to use parentContexts at all (and it should!).

Answer (score 4):

The details for using parent / child contexts are laid out in the [Core Data Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html) document which states:

> You cannot, therefore, use parent contexts created with the thread confinement type (see [“Concurrency Support for Managed Object Contexts”](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-SW1)).

So to answer your question, the parent context has to have a concurrency type of [NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType) or [NSMainQueueConcurrencyType](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSMainQueueConcurrencyType). The child context can have any concurrency type.

For a great overview and lots of sample code, I would check out [Marcus Zarra's Core Data video course](http://ideveloper.tv/video/coredataupdatecourse.html) or the [beta version of his book](http://pragprog.com/book/mzcd2/core-data).

Comment: The doc is not quite clear about this. Referring to `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`, it first says **You cannot use this concurrency type in conjunction with the new nested contexts feature**. And then **You cannot, therefore, use parent contexts created with the thread confinement type**. BUT yes, you are right, IMHO. +1 indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has not released any real documentation other than the [WWDC 2012 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=214) and the [release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html) about parent and child contexts. The video is very detailed about how to use them and the rare cases you may need to use performBlock or performBlockAndWait.

The important thing most people miss is that the concurrency type refers to what thread the context will use to access the rest of the core data stack - not the thread the context is created on. You almost never need to use performBlock or performBlockAndWait in your own code *as long as you continue to implement a thread confinement pattern*. Doing so will often trigger deadlocks (especially if one or more of the contexts are NSMainQueueConcurrencyType).

**NSMainQueueConcurrencyType** - Good for NSManagedObjects that are used in the UI. You should only maintain one of these.

**NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType** - Good for background operations. When importing new objects from an external file or webservice, the parentContext is the main UI context. When you finish creating the objects, `save` automatically notifies the parentContext of the changes. You can also use a private context as the parent of the UI context for loading and saving the store from disk without blocking the UI.

So if you create a child context and execute a fetch request, it uses the thread (designated by concurrency type) to interact with the parent context *automatically*. It will automatically use performBlock appropriately. When you save a child context, the parent context automatically gets the changes merged in without you doing anything on the parent context.

If you are having to use performBlock or performBlockAndWait, you are no longer using the thread confinement pattern. The only time it's valid within the thread confinement pattern is to reach across "cousin" contexts where a parent has multiple children and one child's changes are saved to the parent and the parent pushes those down to the other children.

Comment: I got deadlock WITHOUT performBlock. So I tried that with performBlock.

Comment: The video goes over what causes those deadlocks. Basically, the contexts call performBlock for you to communicate with the rest of the stack. You only use performBlock if you want to be on the thread it uses to communicate with the rest of the core data stack - which is independent of the thread it was created on.

Comment: According to the [Core Data Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html), you should do any work involving a managed object context or managed objects within a `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` call. The one exception is if you're on the main thread and you're using a context with a main queue concurrency type.

Comment: @KrisMarkel From the release notes: "You can use contexts using the confinement pattern just as you have prior to OS X v10.7 and iOS 5. You send the contexts messages directly; it’s up to you to ensure that you send the messages from the right queue." You can wrap everything in blocks, but it is only required when you are potentially communicating across threads - and can cause deadlocks. **Which means always using performBlock and performBlockAndWait will cause more problems that it solves for most use cases**.

Comment: That is true for the confinement concurrency type, but using that means handling concurrency in the old and easy to get wrong way. You're much better off using private queue concurrency and the performBlock methods. Then the framework handles all the concurrency issues for you.

Comment: @KrisMarkel Just to be clear, the private queue type creates a separate private thread from the thread it was created on for communicating with the rest of the core data stack. You only want to be on that queue for that purpose. Creating and editing a managed object on that queue is not useable on the thread the context was created on, which is the whole point of having a context in the first place.

Comment: No. The point of the private queue concurrency type is that you do all your core data operations within a performBlock call, and then you no longer have to worry about thread confinement. It's the entire reason that concurrency types were created. Thread confinement is hard to get right and a lot of people were doing it incorrectly, so the performBlock calls take care of it all for you.

Comment: @KrisMarkel I agree with you - it is meant for use when not using the thread confinement pattern. Notice they use the phrase "confinement pattern" not "confinement concurrency type". The confinement pattern is still recommended. You can still use the confinement pattern with the private and main queue concurrency type. When you use performBlock while implementing your code *in the confinement pattern*, you can unintentionally create deadlocks. The performBlock and performBlockAndWait should only be used when you are NOT using the confinement pattern.

Comment: @KrisMarkel - Thank you for bringing it up. I updated answer with clarification on why performBlock is dangerous when using a thread confinement pattern.

Comment: Your answer talks about using private queue concurrency for background tasks and then says using the performBlock methods is wrong. If your using private queue concurrency, you have to use one of the performBlock methods.

Comment: You use contexts using the queue-based concurrency types in conjunction with two new methods: performBlock: and performBlockAndWait:. You group “standard” messages to send to the context (including initialization such as setting the persistent store coordinator and so on) within a block to pass to one of these methods. The one exception is: if your code is executing on the main thread, you can invoke methods on the main queue style contexts directly instead of using the block based API.